# How to enable CORS in SAP HANA XS project?

Tags: sapui5, hana-xs

I need to resolve the same origin policy restriction in JavaScript client side SAPUI5 application that is consuming an OData service from a cross origin server. In SAP HANA developer guide one of the solutions to this problem is to enable CORS (Cross Origin Resources Sharing).

I tried to enable CORS following the instructions from the developer guide by adding the following configuration to the .xsaccess file:

```
 "cors": [{
    "enabled": true
}]
```

Yet CORS is not enabled! Is there any further configuration I should consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to your ajax-call and check:

```
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
```